# Extracting messages in threads without html or original messages

Tags: python, gmail-api

For any thread query "to:xyz@gmail.com", I've been able to return all the matching thread IDs, and then feed them into the messages get method to return a list of all the messages within all the threads.

However, many of the messages contain all the previous messages, creating a breadcrumb for each message and greatly enlarging the size of each message returned. Other messages also contain html elements.

What's the best way to parse all of this out to just return the messages sent and received, without all the breadcrumb and html excess?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the gmail raw message format, I put this very rough parsing together. The way it works is uses the first content-type to grab the multipart boundary.
It then splits the message up based on boundary and takes the very first section.

This omits all html, and only leaves us with the text message and breadcrumbs to deal with.

After that we can break up the message line by line, remove the remaining content information, take the message, and stop when we arrive at the first reply.

```
multipart_boundary = ''
for r in messages.split('\n'):
    if r.startswith('Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary='):
        multipart_boundary = r[r.find('boundary=') + 9:]
        break

#print multipart_boundary
offset = len(multipart_boundary) + 2
messages = messages[messages.find('--' + multipart_boundary)+offset:]
messages = messages[:messages.find('--' + multipart_boundary)]
newmsg = ""
for line in messages.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('Content-') or line.startswith('>'):
        continue
    elif line.startswith('On') and line.strip().endswith('wrote:'):
        break
    else:
        newmsg = newmsg + "\n" + line

print newmsg
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll try it out - do I need to save the output of the messages in a txt file or can I just plug in the variable it's saved to in the same script? For example, my last variable (messages) is set to equal the GetMessage method decoded into a str by b64.url_safedecode...

Comment: You don't need to use a text file. I will update the code now so it just uses the messages variable.

Comment: So I'm having trouble figuring out where to place this code. When you say you apply it to the raw gmail message, is it after it's decoded by b64 or before? Also, it is just the data/body piece or the entire raw message output?